# Associate a Public Static Ip to Web App in the Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Is possible associate a reserved public ip address to Web App int the azure portal?

[image: Bind External Domain]

**I need to replace this ip (40 112 ...)  for the reserved ip.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. From the FAQ:

> Can I use a reserved IP for all Azure services?
>
> Reserved IPs can only be used for VMs and cloud service instance roles exposed  through a VIP.

**Reserved IP Overview**

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/